# Installing Network Manager on Causes Raspberry Pi To Stop Working

Tags: pi-hole, networkmanager

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W that I am using to setup Pi-hole by following [this guide](https://www.raspberrypi.com/tutorials/running-pi-hole-on-a-raspberry-pi/). The guide requires me to use `nmcli`, which requires me to setup Network Manager. I am following [this guide](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-network-manager/) to setup install it on my Raspberry Pi, but when I run `sudo raspi-config` and attempt to set my network configuration to Network Manager, the menu crashes, the ssh connection is lost, and my Raspberry Pi does not reboot correctly. Even disconnecting and reconnecting it from the power does not successfully reboot it so that I can ssh into it. The only way to ssh back into it is fully reinstalling the OS.

My questions are as follows:

- Why does installing Network Manager on my Raspberry Pi cause it to break like?
- Is there a way to not have to reinstall the OS when this occurs?

Comment: If you are attempting to change networking while using the network over ssh it is hardly surprising. Use a screen & keyboard to setup.

Comment: So it is not possible to switch to NetworkManager over ssh? @Milliways

Comment: Think about that question for just a moment...

Comment: If you want `nmcli`, you would probably be better-served by installing the *new-ish* 'bookworm' distribution - it comes with `nmcli` as the default net mgr.